# Run Asterisk CLI with Java

Tags: java, command-line-interface, asterisk

I am trying to run Asterisk CLI with Java. 
For example

```
asterisk -rx "core show license"
```

I implement Java code like this

```
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("asterisk -rx \"core show license\"");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
```

But what I got is

```
No such command '"core' (type 'core show help core' for other possible commands)
```

from Linux console.

I am wondering what I did mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth would you have to do such thing instead of using the AMI (asterisk manager API)?

Comment: actually, I know it is possible to make it with manager, but I just curious about this.

Comment: @pdeschen "Why on earth" There is limited how to documentation on using API's.

Comment: @Siddharth https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239 + http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Command + http://www.asterisk-java.org/development

Comment: All these links provide the SDK but no HOW TO. Asterisk documentation is good but not complete. I dont think they care too much about solving this issue. As a company becomes bigger they care lesser about smaller problems. If someone is brave enough to venture out there and try out and develop on asterisk, i think its best that we support. We need community support when the company does not provide any. I dont know why but this site never opens for me.. http://www.asterisk-java.org/development

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"asterisk","-rx","\"core show license\""});
```

In your version [exec(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) the String will be tokenized by a default StringTokenizer, that seperates tokens by spaces. That is the reason for the unknown "core command in asterisk.

(Not shure, if the "core show license" command must go into quotes)

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[] {"asterisk", "-rx", "core show license"});
```